# How to close a drop down menu item?

Tags: c#

I use drop down menu.

When you open a drop down menu, reduce using Windows right bottom corner, menu are not closed. When unminimizing engine (with same corner button, or other ways), sometimes menus remains open and causes problem.

So I want to close all menus when engine is minimized. How can I do it?

I saw that they recommend using `HideDropDown()`, but it doesn't work in this case.